# Require password after 3 page views

Tags: wordpress, passwords

How do I require a password after x number of page views (or after x minutes)?

I have a website (running on WP) that I would like to allow free access to visitors for a while, but after a certain time require a password to continue seeing the site. This is to encourage sign up (also free).

I would rather not use a login system, rather a simple password to be entered. Ideally there would be a WP plugin with this feature, but I can't seem to find one.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a plugin that directly implements this behavior, I would question this feature. Of course you can just show a popup without a close button after X minutes but such pages rather encourage your users to leave the page than to sign up (what did you do the last time, did you sign up?). I would rather recommend to use a friendly and non blocking way to inform your users about the advantage of an account or subscription. If your content is good they will be happy to sign up.  Furthermore, to make sure that they just do not reload the page after they were blocked you have to set cookies or track their IP. Both requires at least in the european union a data protection policy. In addition, you would need to implement a flow to bring users back from the registration to their desired content. I don't want to say that this is not possible or that there are no plugins out there that allow such a behavior but the efforts to implement this in a proper way are from my perspective unreasonable considering that there are more user friendly options.